# Setting scroll in fixed 100% height sidebar in css ?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed 100% height side bar that contain several controls.

I'm trying to make the bottom control (green frame) scroll when reaching the screen bottom.

The middle control is an accordion.

I've used a table-row display to automatically adjust the controls height in the side bar.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/bogiguva/1/edit?css)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify height of the green container to use overflow-y:scroll.

you can detect the document end by the following jquery code

```
if (  document.documentElement.clientHeight + 
  $(document).scrollTop() >= document.body.offsetHeight )
```

{

```
alert("You're at the bottom of the page.");
```

}

at this point of scroll you may add css to the green box i.e height :200px (or anything you want)

Comment: You should replace $(document).scrollTop() with document.body.scrollTop